# Change Email signature for in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to know how to change the signature and the "company name" when using Custom policies for the email received from Azure, such as the one to verify the code?

Please, check the image below, where it says "Here"

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into azure portal - select your AAD b2c directory.
Select azure ad blade, properties, and change the tenant name.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft - that is not great, now i can't identify tenants easily in the azure portal, is there another way to do it where the portal name and the email footer are separated